# AngularJs Ajax POST form with file upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to set up a form to be submitted using an ajax request to an api that has already been built using Ajax. For some reason the file just doesn't want to transfer to the system although there is already a back end built to handle this, and it works fine.

My service looks like this based on a tutorial I found here: http://badwing.com/multipart-form-data-ajax-uploads-with-angularjs/

```
addActivity: function(url){
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: REQUEST_URL + 'Volunteering/AddActivity?token=' + token + url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        data: {
            file: $scope.file
        },
        transformRequest: formDataObject
    }).
    then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        return result.data;
    });
},
```

I have a feeling it's just something really minor that i'm missing, can anyone offer some help?

Comment: What is `REQUEST_url`

Comment: a global variable i'm using

Comment: @flashpunk have you placed `$scope.file` like this `<input type="file" ng-model="file"/>`?, cause I too need to upload file/image ajaxly with angularjs

Comment: instead of "data", "params" could help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced a similar problem.

The solution is to use formData

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", $scope.file);
```

and replace

```
data: {
    file: $scope.file
}
```

with

```
data: {
    formdata
}
```

Comment: formdata is not supported in many ie browsers, its supports from ie10 + versions so that its not generic solution

Comment: @Satish Agreed, it is not the best solution. Do you have one to offer up?

Comment: There is no other way to upload file using Ajax apart from XMLHttRequest 2 or say FormData object. I assume that for non compatible browsers, devs use Flash or some other technology.

Comment: Consider IE9 deprecated. It is deprecated in almost every platform (i.e. only supported in vista and windows server 2008). Google does not support IE9. Facebook does not support IE9. MS does not support IE9 for Windows 7+.

Comment: Complete Support Table for FormData: http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata -- I'd say it's more than safe to use it :)

Comment: formdata is the way to go; we're not living in 2011. a non-flash pre-formData solution is to submit to a hidden iframe

Answer (score 8):

I was having trouble implementing file upload with angular + laravel. Every time I tried sending the multipart form, the server wouldn't receive the form data, even tho it was clearly being sent, or so I thought. I finally found [THIS](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) article that solved all my problems.

Long story short, this is the $http call:

```
var data = new FormData();

data.append("file", file);

$http.post("//myDomain.com/api/demo", data, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
    transformRequest: angular.identity
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

The other answer by rolin.tencent.Shenzhen also mentioned setting `Content-Type` as `undefined` to let the browser sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

The data should be `data: $scope.file`

and important thing : you should set `'Content-Type': undefined` to make the browser set the right content type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin, it's highly configurable too: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload